# Variable url in json-script

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, geolocation

Messing around for days know. Learning javascript and jquery a few weeks, it goes well, but sometimes...

For an mobile app i'm trying to get the coordinates. Showing them on page isn't a problem, but I want them elsewhere.

In the main.js

```
var getLocation = function() {
    var suc = function(p) {
        document.getElementById("locatie").innerHTML = "http://www.192.168.1.111/tools/gpslocation.php?lat=" + p.coords.latitude + "&lon= " + p.coords.longitude + "&max=20";
  };

    var locFail = function() {
    };
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(suc, locFail);
};
```

And in the htmlfile

```
<body  onload="getLocation();" >


     <p id="locatie">Finding geolocation...</p></ul>

<div id="geolocation">
Bezig met laden. Momentje geduld</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function(){

 var script=document.createElement('script');
 script.type='text/javascript';
 script.src= "http://www.192.168.1.111/tools/gpslocation.php?lat=53.216493625&lon=6.557756660461426&max=20";
 $("body").append(script);
});

function processTheseTerraces(jsonData){
var shtml = '';
 var results = jsonData.results;
 if(results){
 $.each(results, function(index,value){
 shtml += "<li class='store'><a class='noeffect' href='#'><span class='image' style='background-image: url(pics/terras1.jpg)'></span><span class='comment'>" + value.address + "</span><span class='name'>" + value.building_name + "</span><span class='stars5'></span><span class='starcomment'>132 Beoordelingen</span><span class='arrow'></span></a></li>";
 });

 $("#geolocation").html( shtml );
 }
}
</script>
```

Now I want the coordinates passing through json and load the data. I thought to change

```
   script.src= "http://www.192.168.1.111/tools/gpslocation.php?lat=53.216493625&lon=6.557756660461426&max=20";
```

in

```
script.src= "http://www.192.168.1.111/tools/gpslocation.php?lat=" + p.coords.latitude + "&lon= " + p.coords.longitude + "&max=20";
```

But that doesn't work. Anyone suggestions how I can solve this.

Comment: You're not actually calling an ajax function. You're literally telling the inner HTML of locatie to become the url text. Try using the jquery ajax function and then using that data. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

This: `http://www.192.168.1.111` is just a wrong URL. I guess you need just this: `http://192.168.1.111`

Answer (score 0):

Geolocation can take a long time (multiple seconds). It is an asynchronous request which means that the other javascript code may execute before the geolocation has grabbed the address. The solution is to put any code or function calls that use the location inside the callback function on the `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition`

The JQuery is building the URL before the lat and lng have been defined.

Answer (score 0):

onload="getLocation();" tells that when the document is loaded call getLocation function and inside this function you set the innerHTML of `<P id="locatie">` TAG as: `http://www.192.168.1.111/tools/gpslocation.php?lat=" + p.coords.latitude + "&lon= " + p.coords.longitude + "&max=20`

**So problems are:**

1. If you make a script tag and assign source then browser fetch the source data but writing an url on inner html of a `<p>` tag won't do this and it doesn't make sense.
2. Code fragment below is loaded before the document is loaded but i guess you do not want this:

   jQuery(function(){

   var script=document.createElement('script');
    script.type='text/javascript';
    script.src= "http://www.192.168.1.111/tools/gpslocation.php?lat=53.216493625&lon=6.557756660461426&max=20";
    $("body").append(script);
   });
3. If you want: `script.src= "http://www.192.168.1.111/tools/gpslocation.php?lat=" + p.coords.latitude + "&lon= " + p.coords.longitude + "&max=20";` then you have to define p.coords first and before calling this otherwise p.coords is undefined.

---

Solution i am not sure what you exactly asking so could not answer. Do you want to assign inner HTML of the #locatie element or do you want to load customized script as  tag?

Either ways, you have to make an ajax call to server which maybe like this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://www.192.168.1.111/tools/gpslocation.php",
  data: "lat=" + p.coords.latitude + "&lon= " + p.coords.longitude + "&max=20",

success: function(Result){
   // use Result variable in came from the success function.
   document.getElementById("Your_ID_Goes_Here").innerHTML = "do_Something";
  }
});
```